# Different GCP PubSub dead letter topics for different types of failures

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Push Subscription sending messages to the Cloudrun service. The service sends different HTTP codes for different types of failures. Is it possible to route messages to different dead-letter topics based on the error code? Example: for an HTTP response code 500, send the message to dl-topic1; for an HTTP response code 501, send the message to dl-topic2, etc.

GCP PubSub documentation states the availability of just one additional attribute deliveryAttempt
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#track-delivery-attempts. Nothing else on the type of error.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not a supported feature.

If you want to achieve this for response codes returned by your service, you can choose to actively publish the message to a different topic based on client side logic, and acknowledge the message (response code 200) to Cloud Pub/Sub.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and I handled by putting a Workflow in between the pub/sub and the Cloud Run. This way the Workflow will perform a step according to the status return of the Cloud Run. The other benefit for me was it ack'ed the pub/sub within the timeout, even though my Cloud Run is a long running job (less than 30 mins).

So pub/sub -> workflow -> Cloud Run -> back to workflow which does something based on the status return.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/workflows